# Create a single container instead of 3 different containers

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I saw you were setting up a Docker-compose file but it which creates 3 different containers but wanted to combine those 3 containers to a single container/image instead of setting it up as multiple containers at deployment system.

My current list of containers are as follow:

1. my main container containing my code that I built using Docker File
2. rest 2 are containers of Redis and Postress but wanted to combine them in 1.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: You really don't want to combine them into a single container. That makes so many things more difficult -- for example, that would prevent you from using the official images for postgres and redis, which just gives you a bunch of extra work for no benefit.

Comment: Can you describe your problem of why you want to do this? Maybe we can help you with your real problem. Keep in mind, separation of concern is a basic principle that comes from times when containerization was not even a thing, but containerization follows and builds upon that principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, running `redis`, `postgres`  and your `"main container"` in one container is **NOT** best practice.
Typically you should have 3 separate containers (**single app per container**) communicating over the network. Sometimes we want to run two or more lightweight services inside the same container but `redis` and `postgres` **aren't** such services.
I recommend reading: [best practices for building containers](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-for-building-containers).

---

However, it's possible to have multiple services in the same docker container using the [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/)  process management system.
I will run both `redis` and `postgres` services in one docker container (it's similar to your issue) to illustrate you how it works. It's for demonstration purposes only.

This is a directory structure, we only need `Dockerfile` and `supervisor.conf` (`supervisord` config file):

```
$ tree example_container/
example_container/
├── Dockerfile
└── supervisor.conf
```

First, I created a `supervisord` configuration file  with `redis` and `postgres` services defined:

```
$ cat example_container/supervisor.conf
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:redis] 
command=redis-server # command to run redis service
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/dev/stdout
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 0
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 0


[program:postgres]
command=/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main/ -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf # command to run postgres service
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/dev/stdout
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 0
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 0
user=postgres
environment=HOME="/var/lib/postgresql",USER="postgres"
```

Next I created a simple `Dockerfile`:

```
$ cat example_container/Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:latest
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Installing redis and postgres
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor redis-server postgresql-12

# Copying supervisor configuration file to container
ADD supervisor.conf /etc/supervisor.conf

# Initializing redis and postgres services using supervisord
CMD ["supervisord","-c","/etc/supervisor.conf"]
```

And then I built the docker image:

```
$ docker build -t example_container:v1 .
```

Finally I ran and tested docker container using the image above:

```
$ docker run --name multi_services -dit example_container:v1
472c7b2eac7441360126f8fcd0cc80e0e63ac3039f8195715a3a400f6288a236


$ docker exec -it multi_services bash
root@472c7b2eac74:/# ps aux   
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root           1  0.7  0.1  27828 23372 pts/0    Ss+  10:04   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor.conf
postgres       8  0.1  0.1 212968 28972 pts/0    S    10:04   0:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main/ -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf
root           9  0.1  0.0  47224  6216 pts/0    Sl   10:04   0:00 redis-server *:6379
...

root@472c7b2eac74:/# netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9/redis-server *:6
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8/postgres
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      9/redis-server *:6
```

As you can see it is possible to have multiple services in a single container but this is a **NOT** recommended approach that should be used **ONLY** for testing.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Kubernetes, you can group your containers in a single *[pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/)*, as a deployment unit.

A Pod is the smallest deployable units of computing that you can create and manage in Kubernetes.
It is a group of one or more containers, with shared storage and network resources, and a specification for how to run the containers.

[image: https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/fe03f68d8ede9815184852ca2a4fd30325e5d15a/98064/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/public/images/module_03_pods.svg]

A Pod's contents are always co-located and co-scheduled, and run in a shared context.

That would be more helpful than trying to merge containers together in one container.